# Need to restrict the email notifications to only those tasks created by the specific profiles

Tags: trigger, email, profile, tasks, singleemailmessage

For The above requirement how to restricted email notification for specific profiles.For that i have written a trigger mentioned the below  but that code is not working as expected. could any one help us.

Trigger Code Like This:

```
for(Task tsk : Trigger.New) {
        if(tsk.Status=='Completed' && Trigger.oldMap.get(tsk.Id).Status != 'Completed' && tsk.OwnerId != tsk.CreatedById) {
           if(tsk.Owner.Profile.name!= 'System Administrator') {  
            User theUser = userMap.get(tsk.CreatedById);
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {theUser.Email};
```

Please Find the Code the one which we have tried:

```
trigger TaskEmailNotification  on Task (before update ) {
    Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> UsrId = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> tskIds= new Set<Id>();
    for(Task tsk: Trigger.New){
        if(tsk.Status=='Completed' && Trigger.oldMap.get(tsk.Id).Status != 'Completed' && tsk.OwnerId != tsk.CreatedById){
            ownerIds.add(tsk.CreatedById);      
        }        
    }

    // Build a map of all users who are assigned the tasks
  //  Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id,User>([select Name, Email from User where Id in :ownerIds]);
    //Master
    Map<Id, User> OwnrMap = new map<Id,User>([SELECT Id, Profile.Name from User where Id in :UsrId]);

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailMsglist=new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    for(Task tsk : Trigger.New) {
        if(tsk.Status=='Completed' && Trigger.oldMap.get(tsk.Id).Status != 'Completed' && tsk.OwnerId != tsk.CreatedById) {
             if(tskIds.contains(tsk.Id) && OwnrMap.get(tsk.OwnerId).Profile.Name!= 'Standard Platform User'){
           // User theUser = userMap.get(tsk.CreatedById);
           User theUser = OwnrMap.get(tsk.CreatedById);

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {theUser.Email};
```

Thanks in advacne

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this point and click as follows

1. Add a new custom formula Boolean [polymorphic owner](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/06/cross-object-owner-fields-a-powerful-new-formula-option.html) field on Task: `IsAssigneeGeacSales__c`
2. Set the value of the formula field to:

   ```
   Owner:User.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'
   ```
3. Use normal workflows/process builder criteria:

   ```
   isAssigneeGeacSales &&
   TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Status)) <> TEXT(Status) &&
   CreatedById <> OwnerId
   ```
4. Use normal email alerts

Comment: @shrinivas -- if you're going to edit my answer to change the profile name from GeacSales to System Admin; then shouldn't you have edited all three refs to GeacSales - field name, formula value and usage in workflow criteria? as it stands, the answer is inconsistent. I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to collect `OwnerIds` to run a query on to get their profile names returned in a map so you can test against the profile.Name of 'GEAC Sales'. That info isn't contained in trigger.new. Based on what you've provided, your code should look something like this:

**EDIT**

```
Set<Id>UsrId = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id>tskIds= new Set<Id>();
for(Task tsk : Trigger.New) {
    if(tsk.Status=='Completed' && Trigger.oldMap.get(tsk.Id).Status != 'Completed' && tsk.OwnerId != tsk.CreatedById) {
        UsrId.add(tsk.OwnerId);
        tskIds.add(tsk.Id);
}

Profile p = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'GEAC Sales' limit 1];
map<Id,User>OwnrMap = new map<Id,User>([SELECT Id, ProfileId from User where Id IN: UsrId]);

for(Task tsk : Trigger.New) {
    if(tskIds.contains(tsk.Id) && OwnrMap.get(tsk.OwnerId).ProfileId != p.Id){

        User theUser = userMap.get(tsk.CreatedById);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {theUser.Email};
```

I should add that as written, this restricts the emails based on the profile of the current Owner, not the CreatedById, which is not what you stated in the title of your question. You may want to modify the code to collect CreatedByIds not, OwnerIds.

Comment: Hi Team, As i am Using mentioned above trigger not working still who ever having specific profile they are getting mail. please find the below trigger code the one which we have tried.

Comment: Please use the edit button at the bottom left of your question to update it with any code changes you've made. They're indecipherable when made via comments.

Comment: Please Find my Edit Trigger

Comment: I've just added a separate query for Profile which should solve the issue. Try it and if it doesn't resolve your issue, add debug statements to your trigger and tell us what your debug logs are showing to diagnose why your trigger isn't working for you.

Comment: You're welcome shrinivas. Community etiquette is to help others by marking your question as solved through checking the answer that resolved your issue. If you don't, it leaves the impression to anyone who searches the topic later that your question wasn't answered to your satisfaction. Once you have sufficient reputation, you can also upvote posts and answers.

Comment: Hi,   we are facing another problem in the above trigger ..as of now the above code is working as expected the problem is here in task object we have some record types are there, in that if we select standard record type the above code is working,if we select some RMA updates,Case  record types that time task owner getting the mail like your task has been Completed .can you please help me on that.  thanks

Comment: So you've changed the criteria to Task.Type=`RMA Update` on Case or something similar? Did the createdBy have permission to see that RecordType or is it that those RecordTypes are not being selected in your trigger? Add debug statements to get `tsk.Id`, `tsk.RecordTypeId` and `tsk.Type` to see if they're being selected & added to your set of Records to help debug the issue.

Comment: Hi, Where i need to change criteria Task.Type=RMA Update ? as of now we are not written record type  selection in trigger.I created One List in the Trigger Like  list<Case> listCase = [SELECT RecordType.Name,Contact.Email FROM Case where Id in :ownerIds Limit 5] ,but that code is not working even i was tried with debugs also .So please update me the Logic...Thanks

Comment: I don't know why you're querying Case as opposed Task. I've answered your original question. This is a new question. You need to post a new question with your current code. Feel free to reference this one if you feel it would be helpful.